# SDE with constant coefficients

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, piecewise-continuity

So the simplest possible SDE would be
\begin{equation} 
\begin{cases}
dX_t = a dt + b dW_t, \text{ with } a,b\in \mathbb{R}   \\
X_0 = x_0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

describing a 1-dimensional stochastic process $X_t$ on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ and $t \in [0,\infty)$.

I know that in this case, the distribution of the solution is a Gaussian. So it is enough to characterize $\mathbb{E}[X_t]$ and $\text{Var}(X_t)$. Taking the expectation and variance of the equation, I get that $X_t \sim \mathcal{N}(x_0 + at, b^2t)$.

The problem I am interested in is a piecewise constant SDE, where
$$ a = \begin{cases}
a_1, \text{ if } X_t >0\\
a_2, \text{ if }X_t \leq 0 \end{cases}$$

$$ b = \begin{cases}
b_1, \text{ if } X_t >0\\
b_2, \text{ if }X_t \leq 0 \end{cases}.$$

How would one "piece together" the two solutions on either side of $0$? It would be simple to solve the equation on either side, but I think there would have to be some compatibility equation at 0.

One problem I know is that a Brownian motion will hit $0$ infinitely many times in a time interval $[0,\epsilon)$, which means that each time $X_t=0$, there is a small interval where the process may not be well-defined. I was thinking to fix this by stopping the process everytime it hits $0$, and restarting it after it "escapes" some neighborhood of 0. Perhaps this could be reframed as a reflected diffusion.

Note: there are two relevant solution methods to similar problems that I've seen in the literature, one involving an analytic solution to the constant-coefficients problem ([Karatzas and Shreve](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-12/issue-3/Trivariate-Density-of-Brownian-Motion-Its-Local-and-Occupation-Times/10.1214/aop/1176993230.full)), and a numerical solution to the reflecting boundary problem ([Skorokhod](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1106035?casa_token=qM_WBpriXCgAAAAA:wtIhvgsjyAApLJ6UKRbDGoyX9s7DTICAMPb-AH2fGAgU_VXm5B1lvla62e2-3udTOrrvssUPcw)), not sure which is appropriate here.

Comment: To answer your parenthetical question: Rather $X_t-X_0$ has the written distribution so that given $X_0=x_0$, $X_t\sim \mathcal{N}(x_0+at, b^2 t)$.

Comment: Ah yes, edited!

Answer (score 2):

You could replace the constant coefficients $a$ and $b$ with the coefficient functions in terms of [indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function):
$$a(x)=a_1 \cdot \mathbb{1}_{(0, \infty)}(x)+a_2 \cdot  \mathbb{1}_{(-\infty, 0]}(x)$$
and a similar expression for $b$ but with the constants $b_1, b_2$. Then the SDE is
$$dX_t=a(X_t)dt+b(X_t)dB_t$$

Here is a simulation of a sample-path via the [Euler-Maruyama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method) scheme implemented in R with initial point $x_0=0$, total time $T=1$, and parameters $a_1=-0.05$, $a_2=0.1$, $b_1=0.1$ and $b_2=0.3$ with $n=1000$ time-subintervals: [image: samplepath]

and here is one more simulation that crosses the line $x=0$ with all the same parameters except starting below zero at $x_0=-1$ and running the path for $T=10$. If I can derive any analytic information, I will update this post.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! However I am attempting an analytic solution and looking for some insight on the compatibility conditions needed at the boundary. What happens when the simulation goes below 0?

Comment: @edges900 Indeed, unfortunately, at least at the moment, I cannot find much to say analytically. I added another sample path that starts below zero and eventually crosses $x=0$, just for reference.

Comment: That image makes sense intuitively-- I'm interested in what happens to the transition density as it passes through 0. Interestingly it looks like it passes right through, but I imagine that depends on the parameters. Thanks again